Why sorting SwiftData persisted types is 100 times more time consuming that a not persisted type?
I'm testing sorted(by:) time consuming in iPhone 14 real device and found that sorting @Model types is x100 times more slower.... Why?
        Button("sort 50K [Int]"){
            var numbers = Array(0..<50_000).shuffled()
            let startTime = Date.now
            numbers.sort()
            print("Elapsed time to sort 50K Ints: \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))") // 0.06...
        }
        
        Button("sorted 50K [Int]"){
            let numbers = Array(0..<50_000).shuffled()
            let startTime = Date.now
            let sortedNumbers = numbers.sorted()
            print("Elapsed time to sorted 50K Ints: \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))")// 0.06...
        }
        
        Button("sorted 50K [NoPersistedValueType]"){
            let items = Array(0..<50_000).shuffled().map{NoPersistedValueType(value: $0)}
            let startTime = Date.now
            let sortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.value<$1.value})
            print("Elapsed time to sorted 50K NoPersistedValueType: \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))")// 0.06...
        }
        
        Button("sorted 50K [NoPersistedReferenceType]"){
            let items = Array(0..<50_000).shuffled().map{NoPersistedReferenceType(value: $0)}
            let startTime = Date.now
            let sortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.value<$1.value})
            print("Elapsed time to sorted 50K NoPersistedReferenceType: \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))")// 0.06...
        }
        
        Button("sorted 50K [PersistedItems]"){
            let items: [Item] = Array(0..<50_000).shuffled().map{Item(value: $0)}
            let startTime = Date.now
            let sortedItems = items.sorted(by: {$0.value<$1.value})
            print("Elapsed time to sorted 50K Persisted Items: \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))")// 5.3...
        }

@Model
final class Item {
    var value: Int
    
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct NoPersistedValueType {
    let value: Int
}

class NoPersistedReferenceType {
    let value: Int
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

Real project:
@Model
final public class Item {
    @Relationship(deleteRule:.cascade) var entries: [Entry] = []
    @Transient
    var sortedEntries: [Entry] {
        entries
            .filter{!$0.escaped}
            .sorted(by: {$0.date<$1.date})
    }
    //...
}

Edit:
Button("sorted 5K(not 50K) [PersistedItems] with ModelContext.fetch()"){
    print("Start inserting to ModelContainer...")
    (0..<5_000).forEach{
        modelContext.insert(Item(value: $0))
        if $0 % 1000 == 0 { print("\($0)") }
    }
    try! modelContext.save()
    print("...Ended")
    let startTime = Date.now
    let sortedItems = try! modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Item>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\Item.value)]))
    print("Elapsed time to sorted 5K(not 50K) Persisted Items with ModelContext.fetch(): \(Date.now.timeIntervalSince(startTime))")// 2...
}


Why are you surprised? The values of persisted properties are stored in the model container, so of course there is going to be some overhead. You should never sort persistent models in memory. Fetch a sorted view using the model context or Query instead.

I tried modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Item>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\Item.value)]))but the result is worst. 46" for 5K items when with sorted(by:) is 6" for 50K items. Added code in the question.

Try to call modelContext.save() before fetching, I don't get that kind of results

Yes! 3 seconds for 50K items, far from the result of not persisted types but better than sorting in memory persisted objects...
